# Opentok: OTCameraCaptureResolutionHigh equivalent variable in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, webrtc, opentk, tokbox

I need to change the video quality of my publisher.
I face a conversion problem from **Objective C to Swift 3.0**.

**Here is my Objective C code:**

```
   OTPublisherSettings *settings = [[OTPublisherSettings alloc] init];
settings.name = @"Bob's video";
settings.audioTrack = NO;
settings.videoTrack = YES;
settings.cameraResolution = OTCameraCaptureResolutionHigh;
settings.cameraFrameRate = OTCameraCaptureFrameRate30FPS;
```

**and the converted Swift code is**

```
let settings = OTPublisherSettings()
 settings.name = "Bob's video"
settings.audioTrack = false
settings.videoTrack = true
settings.cameraResolution = OTCameraCaptureResolutionHigh
settings.cameraFrameRate = OTCameraCaptureFrameRate30FPS
```

Last two lines show error messages **"Use of unresolved identifier 'OTCameraCaptureResolutionHigh'".** 
Please advise. It seems swift uses another set of variables for the above.

Comment: sorry I got the answer
settings.cameraResolution =  OTCameraCaptureResolution.hight
        settings.cameraFrameRate = OTCameraCaptureFrameRate.rate30FPS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let settings = OTPublisherSettings()
settings.name = "Bob's video"
settings.audioTrack = false
settings.videoTrack = true
settings.cameraResolution = .high
settings.cameraFrameRate = .30fps
```